# How to create a dynamic sidemenu using ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create a page with login and after user logs in i want to display the dynamic sidemenu when ever user creates that sidemenu  menu components it has to redirect to the respective page and how can i do this if any body got a sample it would be great and im thinking to put component name in the db and via service making it call and the after click it will redirected . if there is another approach please let  me know.**if u people know any dynamic sidemneu sample file using json also please let me know
**

Comment: Show the codez plis

Comment: U want to change menu item with respect to page actions, is it true?

Comment: @Dr. Geek  yeah..